# Result of function is returned without changing list items in if-statement

Tags: python, revit-api, bim

Thanks in advance for your input.

I started learning Python today, because I want to define custom Python nodes in DynamoBIM (Revit) to be more flexible if there aren´t predefined / suitable nodes for my tasks in BIM.

The PythonScript gets input from input nodes, which are `IN[i]`.
In my case I use 2 `bool` values (`IN[0]`, `IN[3]`), 1x `str` `IN[1]`, 1x `float` `IN[2]` and 1x `list` `IN[4]`.

After processing the input via PythonScript it returns a result (`OUT`), which can be used for further tasks.

I tried to attach a prefix in front of every list item, if `IN[0] = True` and add a value `IN[2]` to each list item, before it´s changed. The result is displayed in the watch-node.

---

**In case of `IN[3] = False` (list isn´t replaced) I get the desired result:**

[image]

**In case of `IN[3] = True`, the custom list, doesn´t get adapted (no prefix added, no adding of values):**

[image]

---

**Code of the (integrated) PythonScript:**

```
listing = [0,1,2,3,4,5,None,"null", "", "Text"]
praefix = IN[1]
add = IN[2]

if IN[3]:
    listing = IN[4]

if IN[0]:
    for x in range(len(listing)):
        if isinstance(listing[x], int):
            listing[x] = praefix + str(listing[x] + add)
        
    OUT = listing
    
else:
    
    for x in range(len(listing)):
        listing[x] = listing[x] + add

    OUT = listing
```

---

**Python-code (compilable in online compiler)**

```
listing = [0,1,2,3,4,5,None,"null", "", "Text"]
replacingList = [2,2,3,"Test",4] #IN[4]

boolPraefix = True #IN[0]
praefix = "Indexwert: " #IN[1]
add = 7 #IN[2]
customList = True #IN[3]
replacingList = [2,2,3,"Test",4] #IN[4]

if customList:
    listing = replacingList
    
if boolPraefix:
    for x in range(len(listing)):
        if isinstance(listing[x], int):
            listing[x] = praefix + str(listing[x] + add)

    print(listing)

else:
    
    for x in range(len(listing)):
            listing[x] = listing[x] + add

    print(listing)
```

I tried to reproduce the problem from the integrated script in a online compiler with python code, but in this case the expected result got calculated:

```
['Indexwert: 9', 'Indexwert: 9', 'Indexwert: 10', 'Test', 'Indexwert: 11']
```

Compiled with https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

---

Expected result should be:

[image]

I don't currently have the slightest idea why there are different results between the online compiler code and the integrated PythonScript.

Comment: We can't see the scope. Is this code snippet part of a function? Is this script run multiple times? If so then how is it called? Please post the script with context and example inputs. Better known as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The code snippet is part of the visual programming diagramm and processes the input from input nodes (IN[i]) by a PythonScript. The code runs 1x time and produces a result which get returned to the next connected node (the node with name "watch"). The 5 fields at the left side provide the input, which is used inside the script. Example given: praefix = IN[1] = "True" from field: "place praefix in front of list items?"

Comment: I just thought there might be a very obvious cause, which can be detected easily. I will try to adapt it and put it inside a phyton online compiler, so it ´s more transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Previously had some issues with dynamo and python, in most times I found that the best practice is to use `OUT` only once at the end of the code.
I took your sample and modified it, Try it.
I added an empty list that will be used as a container for the processed list, and assigned it to the output

```
listing = [0,1,2,3,4,5,None,"null", "", "Text"]
#Empty List to use as Output
NewListing =[]
praefix = IN[1]
add = IN[2]

if IN[3]:
    listing = IN[4]

if IN[0]:
    for x in range(len(listing)):
        if isinstance(listing[x], int):
            listing[x] = praefix + str(listing[x] + add)
        
    NewListing = listing
    
else:
    
    for x in range(len(listing)):
        listing[x] = listing[x] + add

    NewListing = listing

OUT NewListing
```

And don't forget to review your indentations within the Python node inside Dynamo.

Comment: Thanks for the input. By combinating your code with casting the items of the custom list to int in a try-block, i was able to produce the expected result. It seams that the list values weren´t recognized as int-values.

Answer (score 2):

Made some additional editing, solution is now working:

**Following (integrated) PythonScript produces the expected result, when used as a node in Dynamo:**

```
listing = [0,1,2,3,4,5,None,"null", "", "Text"]

praefix = IN[1]
add = IN[2]
custom = IN[4]

newListing = []

if IN[3]:
    listing = custom
    
if IN[3]:
    for x in range(len(custom)):
            try:
                listing[x] = int(custom[x])
            except:
                pass

if IN[0]:
    for x in range(len(listing)):
        if isinstance(listing[x], int):
            listing[x] = praefix + str(listing[x] + add)
        
    newListing = listing
    
else:
    
    for x in range(len(listing)):
        listing[x] = listing[x] + add

    newListing = listing

OUT = newListing
```

---

**Result can now also achieved for a custom list:**

[image]